# Tensorflow 2.8 GPU out_of_mem when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to convert .ogg files to tfrecords. I'm running the below code on my GPU using multiprocessing but my GPU RAM gets allocated 100% and the program crashes. Anyone have some input on using multiprocessing with tensorflow or any documentation to best practices? I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

```
import argparse
import math
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

_DEFAULT_META_CSV = 'train_metadata.csv'
_DEFAULT_OUTPUT_DIR = 'tfrecords'

_DEFAULT_DURATION = 4
_DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE = 50000

_DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE = 0.1
_DEFAULT_VAL_SIZE = 0.1

_DEFAULT_NUM_SHARDS_TRAIN = 16
_DEFAULT_NUM_SHARDS_TEST = 4
_DEFAULT_NUM_SHARDS_VAL = 4

_SEED = 42


def _float_feature(list_of_floats):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=list_of_floats))

def _int_features(list_of_ints):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[list_of_ints]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
  if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
    value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _parallelize(func, data):

    processes = cpu_count() - 5
    with Pool(processes) as pool:
        list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(func, data), total=len(data)))


class TFRecordsConverter:
    '''Convert audio to TFRecords'''
    def __init__(self, meta, output_dir, n_shards_train, n_shards_test,
                 n_shards_val, duration, sample_rate, test_size, val_size):        
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        self.duration = duration
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        
        if not os.path.exists(self.output_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.output_dir)

        df = pd.read_csv(meta)
        # Shuffle the data
        self.df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=_SEED)
        
        n_samples = len(df)
        self.n_test = math.ceil(n_samples * test_size)
        self.n_val = math.ceil(n_samples * val_size)
        self.n_train = n_samples - self.n_test - self.n_val
        
        if n_shards_train is None or n_shards_test is None or n_shards_val is None:
            self.n_shards_train = self._n_shards(self.n_train)
            self.n_shards_test = self._n_shards(self.n_test)
            self.n_shards_val = self._n_shards((self.n_val))
        else:
            self.n_shards_train = n_shards_train
            self.n_shards_test = n_shards_test
            self.n_shards_val = n_shards_val
            
        def __repr__(self):
            return ('{}.{}(output_dir={}, n_shards_train={}, n_shards_test={}, '
                    'n_shards_val={}, duration={}, sample_rate={}, n_train={}, '
                    'n_test={}, n_val={})').format(
                self.__class__.__module__,
                self.__class__.__name__,
                self.output_dir,
                self.n_shards_train,
                self.n_shards_test,
                self.n_shards_val,
                self.duration,
                self.sample_rate,
                self.n_train,
                self.n_test,
                self.n_val,
            )
    
    def _n_shards(self, n_samples):
        return math.ceil(n_samples /self._shard_size())
    
    def _shard_size(self):
        shard_max_bytes = 200 * 1024**2
        audio_bytes_per_second = self.sample_rate * 2
        audio_bytes_total = audio_bytes_per_second * self.duration
        shard_size = shard_max_bytes // audio_bytes_total
        return shard_size * self._COMPRESSION_SCALING_FACTOR
        
    def _get_shard_path(self, split, shard_id, shard_size):
        return os.path.join(self.output_dir, f'{split}-{shard_id}-{shard_size}.tfrecord')
    
    def _write_tfrecord_file(self, shard_data):
        shard_path, indices = shard_data
        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(shard_path, options='ZLIB') as out:
            for index in indices:
                file_path = 'train_audio/' + self.df.filename.iloc[index]
                label = bytes(self.df.primary_label.iloc[index], 'utf-8')
            
                raw_audio = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
                audio = tfio.audio.decode_vorbis(raw_audio)
                
                example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    'audio' :  _float_feature(audio.numpy().flatten().tolist()),
                    'label' : _bytes_feature(label)
                }))
                
                out.write(example.SerializeToString())
                
    def _split_data_into_shards(self):
        shards = []

        splits = ('train', 'test', 'validate')
        split_sizes = (self.n_train, self.n_test, self.n_val)
        split_n_shards = (self.n_shards_train, self.n_shards_test,
                          self.n_shards_val)

        offset = 0
        for split, size, n_shards in zip(splits, split_sizes, split_n_shards):
            print('Splitting {} set into TFRecord shards...'.format(split))
            shard_size = math.ceil(size / n_shards)
            cumulative_size = offset + size
            for shard_id in range(1, n_shards + 1):
                step_size = min(shard_size, cumulative_size - offset)
                shard_path = self._get_shard_path(split, shard_id, step_size)
                # Select a subset of indices to get only a subset of
                # audio-files/labels for the current shard.
                file_indices = np.arange(offset, offset + step_size)
                shards.append((shard_path, file_indices))
                offset += step_size

        return shards

    def convert(self):

        """Convert to TFRecords."""
        shard_splits = self._split_data_into_shards()
        _parallelize(self._write_tfrecord_file, shard_splits)

        print('Number of training examples: {}'.format(self.n_train))
        print('Number of testing examples: {}'.format(self.n_test))
        print('Number of validation examples: {}'.format(self.n_val))
        print('TFRecord files saved to {}'.format(self.output_dir))

def main():
    converter = TFRecordsConverter(_DEFAULT_META_CSV,
                                   _DEFAULT_OUTPUT_DIR,
                                   _DEFAULT_NUM_SHARDS_TRAIN,
                                   _DEFAULT_NUM_SHARDS_TEST,
                                   _DEFAULT_NUM_SHARDS_VAL,
                                   _DEFAULT_DURATION,
                                   _DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE,
                                   _DEFAULT_TEST_SIZE,
                                   _DEFAULT_VAL_SIZE)
    converter.convert()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Think i figured it out. I added the below code to the _write_tfrecord_file function:

````
        if gpus:
          try:
            for gpu in gpus:
              tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
          except RuntimeError as e:
            print(e) ```


It'd be great to see if anyone has any better or alternative solutions!
````

Comment: Have you tried lowering your sample rate ``_DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE`` ?

Comment: Yea, i edited in some code with how i was able to make it work.

Comment: I’ll put this as an answer incase someone has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to lower your sample rate. This will use a large amount memory on the gpu. For you, lower this variable:

```
_DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE
```